# TeamViewer installed but not running on CentOS

Tags: ssh, centos5, teamviewer

I followed these `http://www.tecmint.com/how-to-install-teamviewer-8-on-linux-distributions/` steps and installed TeamViewer on my CentOS5 server without any errors in SSH but when I try to start TeamViewer I am just getting the following output but I can't find my TeamViewer username and password to try to connect to my server.

```
root@vps [~]# teamviewer

    Init...
    Checking setup...
    Launching TeamViewer...
    root@vps [~]# teamviwer -info
    -bash: teamviwer: command not found    
root@vps [~]# /usr/bin/teamviewer -info

Init...
Checking setup...

Launching TeamViewer...
root@vps [~]# whereis teamviewer
teamviewer: /usr/bin/teamviewer /etc/teamviewer
root@vps [~]# /usr/bin/teamviewer -help

Init...
Checking setup...
Launching TeamViewer...
root@vps [~]#
```

Can anyone help me finding my TeamViwer id and password to connect to my Server. Thanks.